# I have problem with add SideMenu my application

Tags: java, codenameone

when i use the code to add SideMenu i cant java give me you have problem but i cant fix the problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEkDu.png)

can help me to fix the code or give me another code.

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
Toolbar tb = hi.getToolbar();
Image icon = theme.getImage("mu.png");
Container topBar = BorderLayout.east(new Label());
topBar.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, new Label("Cool App
 Tagline...", "SidemenuTagline","));
topBar.setUIID("SideCommand");
tb.addComponentToSideMenu(topBar);
tb.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Home", FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, e ->
 {});
tb.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Website", FontImage.MATERIAL_WEB, e ->
 {});
tb.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Settings", FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS, e
 -> {});
tb.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("About", FontImage.MATERIAL_INFO, e ->
 {});
hi.addComponent(new Label("Hi World"));
hi.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

`theme` is the resource file that should have been created. If you're in the main class the `theme` variable should already be there as a result of creating the main class. If not you can create it in the body of the method by adding this line before your code:

```
Resources theme = getGlobalResources();
```

Notice you need to explicitly add the image `mu` to the res file using the designer tool or CSS...

I also noticed you have a follow up problem with this code:

```
topBar.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, new Label("Cool App
 Tagline...", "SidemenuTagline","));
```

In Java you can't break a string in the middle, if you want to add a newline you need to use `\n` as such:

```
topBar.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, new Label("Cool App\nTagline...", "SidemenuTagline","));
```